# Get LIMIT value for a Select query in Cassandra java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

How can I access the LIMIT clause on a SELECT statement in Cassandra? Suppose that I have the following SELECT statement

```
Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("test","users");
    select.limit(10);
```

Then somewhere else in the code I want to get the LIMIT clause(in this example 10). Is there an API through which I could access it?

Comment: did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36061457/4828463

Comment: No this is different, I need to extract the "LIMIT" object value from the select object. In the code its a private member of the SELECT class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select.getQueryString` to get the full query string and then filter the string to get what you need.

Comment: True, but this requires lots and lots of string manipulation and handling. I was looking for a cleaner approach. The value  is write there already